# How to recognize whether the process is the IIS worker process from within a .NET code?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have a .NET infra code running both within the IIS worker process and within a desktop client app. How can the .NET code determine whether it is running within an IIS worker process?

I know that I could check the name of the process (w3wp.exe, for instance), but I would like a more robust approach.

Thanks.

**EDIT1**

I wish to make a side note. This is not a production need. I need this information to enable certain scenarios useful during the development and testing phase. Specifically to ease the testing of secure vs non secure configurations.

Comment: I've found, in my experience, that when your code needs to know things like this, that your design is incorrect.  But, that's always the harder fix in the end.

Comment: No fear. I have added a side note to the question to clarify things a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use properties of the [HttpRuntime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.aspx) class which will be null if the current hosting environment is not ASP.Net, e.g.:

```
bool isHttpRuntime = (HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppId != null)
```

This approach is more robust than using 'HttpContext.Current != null' as this will give false negatives under ASP.Net environments where the current thread is not a request thread e.g. it's a ThreadPool thread used directly or indirectly as a result of using Task Parallel Library for instance.

Comment: Excellent, exactly my case where HttpContext.Current is null.

Answer (score 3):

If the code runs on an IIS worker proces in a synchronous manner in response to a HTTP request, then you can check if `HttpContext.Current != null`. It will be null in a desktop context (but if it's async in web it will also be null)

Comment: Null in my case, however checking HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppId works.

Answer (score 0):

You can check existent of HttpContext.Current ...etc.
If you run in IIS, it will get current context. And in app, there is no context.

Comment: Null in my case, however checking HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppId works.